# constructor opens a file with a given filename c++

Tags: c++, file, constructor

In my code below errors occur and the program will not run, I am required to make a Constructor that must open the file with the given filename. If the filename does not exist then it Prints an error message and terminates the program.

Below is the code that I have done so far in C++:

```
#include "ReadWords.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

ReadWords::ReadWords(const char filename[])
{
    wordfile.open(filename);
    if (!wordfile)
    {
        cout << "cannot make " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void ReadWords::close()
{
    wordfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific when you say "errors occur"? What errors? What do they say? Are they compile time or runtime errors?

Comment: Can you please post all of the code? this looks like only a part of it.

Comment: What is the type of `wordfile`?

Comment: it's more normal to place your own includes *after* the standard includes

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try including fstream to the top of your file and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `wordfile` is of type `std::fstream`. If your `ReadWords.h` `#include`s `<fstream>`, it should work ([compiles and works as expected](http://goo.gl/fIqQhw)).

By the way, it's a bad practice to use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Also, since you use C++, take a look at [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). It's safer than using plain `char*` or `char[]`.